# /etc/dhcpcd.conf missing on Rasbian

Tags: raspbian-buster, dhcp, static-ip

I am trying to setup a static IP for my Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 buster, connected to the router via an ethernet cable) that is running OMV (5.6.3-1) according to the "Conquer the Command Line" by Richard Smedley. It describes to modify the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file, but when I try to see the contents of the file with

> `cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf`

I get an error saying that this file does not exist. Is there another way to setup a static IP (all the methods I have found on the Interner use this file)? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMV uses systemd-networkd and removes dhcpcd on installation.

This should be used to configure the network including setting IP addresses and (from what I remember) has methods to facilitate this.

If you install another network manager the results will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

Configuration should be in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file is a part of `dhcpcd5` package, to solve your issue, you can install it:

```
sudo apt install dhcpcd5
```

Answer (score 0):

I logged into the UI as admin then went to http://ipaddress/#/network/interfaces there was a plus + in upper left and added wlan, put in my ssid / password and set to dhcp and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for the following goes to "Luis Fernando Javier Velázquez Sosa" who posted a YouTube video titled: "Wifi Problems Raspberry Pi - dhcpcd not running".

The steps in his video solved the problem for me.
Steps include turning power management off:
Run on the command line: **iwconfig**
Run on the command line: **sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off**
dhcp should now be viewable!!!