# I am using Raspberry pi 4b, when I try to connect with wifi a problem could not communicate with wpa_supplicant

Tags: pi-4

I am using lite os (for using open media vault 5). Yesterday I use my wifi with my pi and it works fine. But after install OMV5 I tried to connect with my wifi but a problem occurred. It says
`Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant`

Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/etc/dhcpcd.conf missing on Rasbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/123897/etc-dhcpcd-conf-missing-on-rasbian)

Answer (score 2):

OMV installs systemd-networkd and disables dhcpcd. Whatever you had before (which you have not detailed) is irrelevant.

You need to use OMV to setup networking.